# is it possible creation of duplicate ip in this code?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a popup rotator that count unic user's ip per day(NO duplicate ip is allowed for user in same date)

```
$userip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `ip` FROM  `popupip` where ip = '$userip' AND userid = $secid AND date='$date'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num > 0) {
    // **it is duplicate Do not insert it in popupip table**
    }else{
    // **it is not duplicate ip insert it in popupip table**
    }
```

above code is an example.I know full code.

but when I look to my phpmyadmin `popupip` table there is a few duplicate ip for user (the exact same ip address for the user on the same date)

how is it possible?

**extra information:** 
in `popupip` `userid` is int(11) , `date` is "date type like 2014-05-30" and `ip` is varchar.
 this page may opens "as fast as possible at the same time" by popup pages. is there a relation between openning a page fast at same time by a user and duplicate ip creation? is there a bug in MySQL? (maybe a big bug!!!!)

Comment: bad idea IP !=person, 1 person can have many IP's. one IP could be thousands of different people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It's a classical case of a race condition.

The quick explanation:

There is a chance that 2 requests *simultaneously* pass the first check, get `$num == 0` and both insert a new row.

To eliminate it you need to create a `UNIQUE` constraint that covers `(user_id, ip, date)` columns

The long explanation:

- [Wikipedia - Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software)
- [Stackoverflow - What is a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550/251311)

Comment: but ip is not unic totally. next day ip is allowed. also php tell me that $num == 0 and base of this information I pay to person.

Comment: @محمد علی پور فتحکوهی: I have already explained how it's possible. See "quick explanation" and "long explanation" correspondingly.

Answer (score 2):

If multiple requests are coming from the same ip at the same time, it is possible that a few of them are executing the select query before any of them executes the insert query (resulting in multiple inserts with the same ip and date).

A solution for this is to create a UNIQUE index with ip, user_id and date (you can easily do this in phpMyAdmin by running the query below):

```
ALTER TABLE `popupip` ADD UNIQUE (`ip`, `user_id`, `date`);
```

After that you can optimize your code and simply execute an "INSERT IGNORE" query that only inserts if the combination (ip, user_id, date) doesn't already exist in the table:

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `popupip` (`ip`, `user_id`, `date`) VALUES ('$userip', $secid, '$date');");
```

With this solution you don't need to do the extra "SELECT" query, or the "if" to check if there are results.

Comment: Edited solution because of small syntax errors, please use current version of the answer.

Comment: Can I Use if (mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `popupip` ...){}else{}  ?